# javascript: store functions as array

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays

Normally we can do this:

```
var somefunc = function(){
    this.func1 = function(){ .... }
    this.func2 = function(){ .... }
};
myvar = new somefunc();
```

Then we can call `myvar.func1()` to run the function.

But, just my thinking. Is it possible to store functions into array and then we can just run all the functions in the array by loop through the array? If possible, then how can I push a function into array?

Thank you.

Comment: It is very tempting to post an answer that only says 'Yes it is'.

Comment: To answer "how can I push a function into array?", with [`Array.prototype.push`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/push), just like you would with any other item you can push into an array, since functions are first-class citizens in JavaScript.

Comment: Why would you ask such a question instead of trying it out!? Even if you don't have node or don't know the dev tools console, you could just create a little fiddle. Why!?

Comment: I tried but it didn't work, so I thought it cannot be done. Anyway, after referring to some of example code here, I manage to get it works. Thanks a lot for everyone help here. Really appreciate it.

Comment: In such cases it is better if you post your (failed) attempt.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Sure you can, something like this

```
var arr = [
    function() {
        console.log('fn 1')
    },
    function() {
        console.log('fn 2')
    },
    function() {
        console.log('fn 3')
    }
]

arr.forEach(function(el) {
    el();
});
```

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/ndN4H/)

Works perfectly fine, the same with objects or anywhere else you'd like to store a function, as functions are just objects

to push another function to the array, you'd do

```
arr.push(
    function() {
        console.log('fn 4')
    }
);
```

easy as that

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer. I try with your example and it works fine until I test with IE8. On IE8, error point to `arr.forEach(function(el) {}`, with message: `Object doesn't support this property or method` How can I get it works on IE8? Thank you.

Answer (score 3):

Functions in javascript are first class citizens, so the answer is yes.

From wikipedia:
"In computer science, a programming language is said to have first-class functions if it treats functions as first-class citizens. Specifically, this means the language supports passing functions as arguments to other functions, returning them as the values from other functions, and assigning them to variables or storing them in data structures."

Answer (score 3):

Yes, it is possible. Have you tried it? It works just like you would expect:

```
var funcs = [
  function (){ console.log('foo'); },
  function (){ console.log('bar'); },
];

for (var i = 0; i < funcs.length; i++) {
  funcs[i]();
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Yes you can :

```
var lx = [
        function(x){ console.log(x) },
        function(y){ console.log(y) }
    ];

for(var i=0; i<lx.length; i++)
    lx[i](i);
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes

```
var myArrayOFunctions = [
    function() { .... },
    function() { .... }
]

myArrayOFunctions[0]();   // runs the first function
```

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/6VB6Y/

The nice part of using an array (versus using an object) is that you can loop through them in order with a simple `for` loop, whereas using a `for...in` on an object does not guarantee the order. Also, you can `push` new functions into your array easily:

```
myArrayOFunctions.push(function() { .... });
```

So you can provide a simple way to add hooks in your code where somebody using your code can attach new functions to execute when some event happens.